# Downloading file with Javascript is giving "Failed - No file" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, google-chrome, download

I am trying to download a file `test.txt` when a button is clicked in a React Javascript project.
My `App.js` and `test.txt` files are in the same directory.

I have the following code in `App.js`:

```
<a href='test.txt' download target="_blank" id="download"/>
```

and

```
document.getElementById('download').click();
```

However, when the download happens it says **"Failed - No file"**.
The path `href='test.txt'` is definitely correct as my IDE correctly navigates me to the file when I click that path.
I am using Chrome. Any ideas what is causing this issue?

Comment: Do you have a `<base>` tag in your `<head>` section (or anywhere else)?

Comment: @Viney I used the boilerplate Reactjs project code and no this doesn't contain a `<base>` tag, what should I put in this tag?

Comment: Do that later but as a simple fix first try `<a href='/test.txt' download target="_blank" id="download"`